# How to use get_orderbook_tickers for a specific symbol?

Tags: python, cryptocurrency, binance

I am trying to get bid/ask prices for BTCUSDT i am not sure how to specify this in my statement:

```
order_book = client.get_orderbook_tickers()
```

I have tried:

```
order_book = client.get_orderbook_tickers("symbol"= "BTCUSDT")
```

I get errors

Comment: Please post the full traceback of the error. What make you think this function can do what you want? Have you read the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

turns out the correct way is:

```
order_book = client.get_order_book(symbol= 'BTCUSDT')
```